# Create a new field by extracting data from two existing fields in Logstash

Tags: elasticsearch, logging, logstash

I have created two fields from my logs as shown below:

```
names: "LeBron", "Jordan", "Philips", "Samuel"
threepointers: "100", "100", "90", "50"
```

`names` and `threepointers` are both of type `string`. This data has already been extracted from the logs and the log looks something like this:

```
|1 = LeBron| 2 = 100 | 1 = Jordan | 2 = 100 | 1 = Philip | 2 = 90 | 1 = Samuel | 2 = 50 |
```

where I extract all the 1s and 2s using `kv` and `field_split, include_keys` methods and then `mutate` on these numbers to `rename` them to `names` and `threepointers`

I would like to create a new field - bestplayers containing all those player names having threepointers = 100 only.
So, essentially I would like to have a result like this:

`bestplayers: "LeBron", "Jordan"`

Any help would be appreciated! Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I would look at the [ruby filter](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/logstash/current/plugins-filters-ruby.html) as an option for this. It allows arbitrary ruby code to be used to filter/modify event data. Once you have done calculations and decided which fields you would like to add, you can use the add_field option to do just that and the remove_field option to delete any of the older unaggregated/filtered information from the event.